# how do I import an external css library to angular2-seed starter project?

Tags: css, angular

I'm building a web app with Angular and using angular2-seed (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) as a starter. However I also have an external stylesheet and a related js file that I need to use as a global style across the entire project. They are basically a *.min.css and a .min.js file. How should I configure the project so that it can correctly import them ? I tried linking them in index.html but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is JS or Css library, if you are not using Angular cli, I mean if you are using simple starter setup for angular2, than you have to use in only `index.html` automatically the effect of css and js is reflected to whole app. But yes, as an alternate you also can embed your css file in particular component in the list of `styleUrls` array of component.

As an example, you have to install a Bootstrap plugin with css as well as js too. than you just have to import just in index.html automatically all the effect are reflacted to whole app.

Comment: The gulp scripts run in this angular2-seed does weird things with extra .js/.ts files.  Theoretically it is done using https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-scripts-and-styles but I'm finding it hard to get working for my own outside of node_modules.  I'm still working on it.